# Given XOR & SUM of two numbers. How to find the numbers?

Tags: math, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bitwise-xor

Given XOR & SUM of two numbers. How to find the numbers?
For example, x = a+b, y = a^b; if x,y are given, how to get a, b?
And if can't, give the reason.

Comment: If you had actually cut-and-pasted the assignment, the grammar would be better.

Comment: You can't. Counterexample: x=9, y=5: 3+6==9, 3^6==5. 2+7==9, 2^7==5.

Comment: Also, why is this tagged `bitwise-and`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This cannot be done reliably. A *single* counter-example is enough to destroy any theory and, in your case, that example is `0, 100` and `4, 96`. Both of these sum to `100` and xor to `100` as well:

```
  0 = 0000 0000            4 = 0000 0100
100 = 0110 0100           96 = 0110 0000
      ---- ----                ---- ----
xor   0110 0100 = 100    xor   0110 0100 = 100
```

Hence given a sum of `100` and an xor of `100`, you cannot know *which* of the possibilities generated that situation.

For what it's worth, this program checks the possibilities with just the numbers `0..255`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void output (unsigned int a, unsigned int b) {
    printf ("%u:%u = %u %u\n", a+b, a^b, a, b);
}

int main (void) {
    unsigned int limit = 256;
    unsigned int a, b;
    output (0, 0);
    for (b = 1; b != limit; b++)
        output (0, b);
    for (a = 1; a != limit; a++)
        for (b = 1; b != limit; b++)
            output (a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

You can then take that output and massage it to give you all the repeated possibilities:

```
testprog | sed 's/ =.*$//' | sort | uniq -c | grep -v ' 1 ' | sort -k1 -n -r
```

which gives:

```
255 255:255
128 383:127
128 319:191
128 287:223
128 271:239
128 263:247
:
and so on.
```

Even in that reduced set, there are quite a few combinations which generate the same sum and xor, the worst being the large number of possibilities that generate a sum/xor of `255/255`, which are:

```
255:255 = 0 255
255:255 = 1 254
255:255 = 2 253
255:255 = <n> <255-n>, for n = 3 thru 255 inclusive
```

Answer (score 3):

It has already been shown that it can't be done, but here are two further reasons why.

For the (rather large) subset of a's and b's `(a & b) == 0`, you have `a + b == (a ^ b)` (because there can be no carries) (the reverse implication does not hold). In such a case, you can, for each bit that is 1 in the sum, choose which one of `a` or `b` contributed that bit. Obviously this subset does not cover the entire input, but it at least proves that it can't be done in general.

Furthermore, there exist many pairs of `(x, y)` such that there is *no* solution to `a + b == x && (a ^ b) == y`, for example (there are more than just these) all pairs `(x, y)` where `((x ^ y) & 1) == 1` (ie one is odd and the other is even), because the lowest bit of the xor and the sum are equal (the lowest bit has no carry-in). By a simple counting-argument, that must mean that at least *some* pairs `(x, y)` must have *multiple* solutions: clearly all pairs of `(a, b)` have some pair of `(x, y)` associated with them, so if not all pairs of `(x, y)` can be used, some other pairs `(x, y)` must be shared.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution to get all such pairs

Logic: 
let the numbers be a and b, we know

```
s = a + b
x = a ^ b
```

therefore

```
x = (s-b) ^ b
```

Since we know x and we know s, so for all ints going from 0 to s - just check if this last equation is satisfied

here is the code for this

```
public List<Pair<Integer>> pairs(int s, int x) {
    List<Pair<Integer>> pairs = new ArrayList<Pair<Integer>>();
    for (int i = 0; i <= s; i++) {
        int calc = (s - i) ^ i;
        if (calc == x) {
            pairs.add(new Pair<Integer>(i, s - i));
        }
    }
    return pairs;
}
```

Class pair is defined as

```
class Pair<T> {
    T a;
    T b;

    public String toString() {
        return a.toString() + "," + b.toString();
    }

    public Pair(T a, T b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

Code to test this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Pair<Integer>> pairs = new Test().pairs(100,100);
    for (Pair<Integer> p : pairs) {
        System.out.println(p);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0,100
4,96
32,68
36,64
64,36
68,32
96,4
100,0
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have a , b the sum = a+b = (a^b) + (a&b)*2 this equation may be useful for you